# C# method-chaining in generic classes with inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, extension-methods, method-chaining

I have class A and classes B and C which inherit from A.
I tried to implement them like this:

```
public static class Extension
    {
        public static List<T> WithYchangeByX<T>(this List<T> list, string firstX, string newY) where T : A<T>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list[i].X.Split(' ')[0].Equals(firstX))
                {
                    list[i] = list[i].WithY(newY);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    }

    public abstract class A<T> where T : A<T>
    {
        public string X { get; }
        public string Y { get; }

        abstract public T WithX(string x);

        abstract public T WithY(string y);
    }

    class B: A<B>
    {
        public new string X { get; }
        public new string Y { get; }
        public DateTime Bspecial { get; }
        public static B Default { get; }

        public B(string x, string y, DateTime bSpecial)
            => (X, Y, Bspecial) = (x, y, bSpecial);

        override public B WithX(string x)
            => new B(x, this.Y, this.Bspecial);

        override public B WithY(string y)
            => new B(this.X, y, this.Bspecial);

        public B WithBspecial(DateTime bSpecial)
            => new B(this.X, this.Y, bSpecial);
    }

    class C: A<C>
    {
        public new string X { get; }
        public new string Y { get; }
        public int Cspecial { get; }
        public static C Default { get; }

        public C(string x, string y, int cSpecial)
            => (X, Y, Cspecial) = (x, y, cSpecial);

        override public C WithX(string x)
            => new C(x, this.Y, this.Cspecial);

        override public C WithY(string y)
            => new C(this.X, y, this.Cspecial);

        public C WithCspecial(int cSpecial)
            => new C(this.X, this.Y, cSpecial);
    }
```

I need this code to work:

```
var b1 = B.Default.WithX("string").WithY("string").WithBspecial(new DateTime(2000, 1, 28));
var b2 = B.Default.WithX("string").WithY("string").WithBspecial(new DateTime(2000, 1, 17));
var c1 = C.Default.WithX("string").WithY("string").WithCspecial(5);

List<A> a1 = new List<A> { b1, b2, c1};

var a2 = a1.WithYchangeByX(x: "string", y: "string");
```

All is working, only the line `List<A> a1 = new List<A> { b1, b2, c1};` is not working. It writes an error that I need to use generic type A but it is an infinitely recursive type when I try to write it. Can you help me somehow? Thanks!

Comment: Note that you have a copy-paste error in `C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WithYchangeByX` method doesn't actually care about the generic parameter `T` that much, so you can introduce a non-generic interface `IA`, and make it work with that instead:

```
public interface IA
{
    string X { get; }
    string Y { get; }
    IA WithX(string x);
    IA WithY(string y);
}

public abstract class A<T> : IA where T : A<T>
{
    public string X { get; }
    public string Y { get; }

    abstract public T WithX(string x);

    abstract public T WithY(string y);

    IA IA.WithX(string x) => WithX(x);

    IA IA.WithY(string y) => WithY(y);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
public static List<IA> WithYchangeByX(this List<IA> list, string firstX, string newY)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list[i].X.Split(' ')[0].Equals(firstX))
        {
            list[i] = list[i].WithY(newY);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

You can then create a `List<IA>` and pass it to this method.

Note that now you lose the generic version of `WithYchangeByXImpl`. If you want to keep it, you can do something like:

```
private static List<T> WithYchangeByXImpl<T>(List<T> list, string firstX, string newY, Action<int, List<T>> consumer) where T: IA
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list[i].X.Split(' ')[0].Equals(firstX))
        {
            consumer(i, list);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

// these look to be the same, but they actually infer a different type parameter for WithYchangeByXImpl
public static List<IA> WithYchangeByX(this List<IA> list, string firstX, string newY)
    => WithYchangeByXImpl(list, firstX, newY, (i, list) => list[i] = list[i].WithY(newY));

public static List<T> WithYchangeByX<T>(this List<T> list, string firstX, string newY) where T: A<T>
    => WithYchangeByXImpl(list, firstX, newY, (i, list) => list[i] = list[i].WithY(newY));
```

Now this code compiles:

```
var b1 = B.Default.WithX("string").WithY("string").WithBspecial(new DateTime(2000, 1, 28));
var b2 = B.Default.WithX("string").WithY("string").WithBspecial(new DateTime(2000, 1, 17));
var c1 = C.Default.WithX("string").WithY("string").WithCspecial(5);

List<IA> a1 = new List<IA> { b1, b2, c1 };

var a2 = a1.WithYchangeByX("string", "string");
```